# Unity Transparent Material Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this issue

[image]

[image]

Material Settings

[image]

and I dont know what causing the problem. I made Surface Type = Transparent because need to change opacity of object.

I also tried it with shader graph, I didn't have much hope so I did an extremely quick search on the internet and created a shader graph like this.

Custom Shader Graph

[image]

Shader Graph Result

[image]

I made this transparent material and added the code on lit.shader

```
[ToggleUI] _CastShadows("Cast Shadows", Float) = 1.0
```

that's why you don't see the "cast shadows" part on your project, this is not causing the problem I think. nothing changed at all while I tested it with and without it.

I'm Using URP Renderer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If someone has a problem like this in the future,

I made [dithering shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uctu1.png) to solve this, [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwHAy.png) are satisfied me.